# IDEA, Android. Get resource by id

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I started to use IntelliJ IDEA for Android development.
I receive following exception in some locale:

```
02-04 12:13:38.518: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f090132
```

In Eclipse I can review gen/R.java and find assumtation about resource. But in IDEA 12 gen/R.java file is empty.

Is it possible to find resource name by its ID #0x7f090132 with IDEA?

Thanks.

Comment: R.java shouldn't be empty on idea... sounds like a project configuration problem ...

Comment: It is behaviour of IDEA 12.0. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99045